# Error al instalar jetstrap en laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer

estoy presentando problemas al instalar la libreria nascent-africa/jetstrap en laravel, la libreria es para quitar el tailwindcss y utilizar boostrap, el proyecto es desde cero y marca el siguiente error.

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - nascent-africa/jetstrap[1.0, ..., v1.3.1] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.2.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - nascent-africa/jetstrap[v1.4, ..., v1.4.1, v2.0, ..., v2.5.3] require illuminate/support ^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - nascent-africa/jetstrap v2.5.4 requires illuminate/support ^8.0|^9.0 -> found illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.10] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires nascent-africa/jetstrap * -> satisfiable by nascent-africa/jetstrap[1.0, ..., v1.4.1, v2.0, ..., v2.5.4].

You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require nascent-africa/jetstrap:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require nascent-africa/jetstrap:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

aqui la url de la libreria: https://github.com/nascent-africa/jetstrap

Comment: Hola, prueba con este enlace, a mi me funcionó, [Bootstrap con Laravel Jetstream](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwixrsjnlJyAAxXDSDABHWWADp0QtwJ6BAgPEAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DWt-OuBX6lEc&usg=AOvVaw0AVVCBO_x8N-eHmt2p2qA1&opi=89978449). Saludos